# Passing Array of Strings to LINQ Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, parameters

Could someone tell me how to handle passing an array of strings to my LINQ stored procedure?

The storedProc was created by dragging an existing sproc onto the dbml page.  storedProc takes 3 (or any number) of parameters that I determine the value of in `GetStringParams()`.

The error: `No overload for storedProc takes 1 argument`

```
DataClassDataContext db = new DataClassDataContext();
//storedProc takes 3 params
gridview.DataSource = db.storedProc(GetStringParams());
gridview.DataBind();

private string[] GetStringParams()
{
    string[] params = new string[3];    
    //Perform some logic here to determine which params to pass
    if (somethingIsTrue)
        params = new string[] { "param1", "param2", "param3" };
    else if (somethingElseIsTrue)
        params = new string[] { "param1", "param2", "" };
    else
        params = new string[] { "", "", "" };
    return params;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.  I searched for this question but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.  Preferably not having to modify the sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataClassDataContext db = new DataClassDataContext();
//storedProc takes 3 params
string[] param = GetStringParams();
gridview.DataSource = db.storedProc(param[0], param[1], param[2]);
gridview.DataBind();

private string[] GetStringParams()
{
    //Perform some logic here to determine which params to pass
    if (somethingIsTrue)
        return new string[] { "param1", "param2", "param3" };
    else if (somethingElseIsTrue)
        return new string[] { "param1", "param2", "" };
    else
        return new string[] { "", "", "" };
}
```

You can't pass an array to a multi-parameter method unless the method asks for a params array.